# Выражение "факт тот, что"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, фразеология

Скажу коротко: мне это выражение не нравится. Наряду с выражением "факт в том, что". Мне кажется, что так странно говорить, потому что, когда так говорят, ссылаются на факт, о котором раньше не было речи.

А может, "факт" в таких случаях используется в другом значении? Казалось бы, значения *реальность, действительность* с Грамоты подходят, однако говорится, что они могут быть, когда "факт" сказуемое.

Справедливости ради надо отметить, что даже такие великие писатели, как Лев Толстой и Достоевский, так выражались:

> **Факт тот ― что** прежние позиции были сильнее и что Бородинская позиция (та, на которой дано сражение) не только не сильна, но вовсе не есть почему-нибудь позиция более, чем всякое другое место в Российской империи, на которое, гадая, указать бы булавкой на карте. [Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир. Том третий (1867-1869)]
>
> **Факт тот, что** господин Голядкин-старший, в здравом виде, по собственной воле своей и при свидетелях, торжественно пожал руку того, кого называл смертельным врагом своим. [Ф. М. Достоевский. Двойник (1846)

*Какие будут соображения по этому поводу?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это выражение, которым я не пользуюсь, но судя по (множественно находящимся) книгам, оно издавна широко употреблялось и потому вполне литературно. Оно приводится в словаре Ожегова, хотя и  без комментария.  Мне оно не близко из-за неясности его буквального смысла (неразложимости на части), однако *ссылки* на что-либо я в нём не усматриваю: местоимение "**тот**" выполняет здесь не указательную, а некую "*утвердительную*" функцию, условно противоположную той, что свойственна частице "*не*" в выражении сомнения "**не факт, что**". *Ссылка* же имеет место в другом выражении,  "**тот факт, что**" (за ним следует не только содержание "факта", но и обязательный предикатив предложения, в котором раскрытый факт - подлежащее). Общее значение выражения "**факт тот, что**": ***имело место то***, о чём говорится вслед за ним. Мне оно представляется родственным выражению "**факты таковы(, что)**" и как бы приводит его к единственному числу (в смысловом отношении здесь "*(факт) тот*" = "*(факт) таков*").

Выражение "**факт в том, что**" как попытка уйти от рассматриваемого выражения (для придания ему буквального смысла), на мой взгляд, не достигает цели: то, что *является фактом*, элементом действительности, подменяется буквально *содержащим факт*. Чем-то это напоминает канцеляризм брежневской эпохи "в этой связи" (вместо "в связи с этим") - в нём как раз содержится неестественная *ссылка* на ранее не упоминавшуюся "связь", что разрушает буквальный смысл ясного исходного выражения. Это вне зависимости от фиксации словарями распространившихся выражений разного стилевого качества.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр! Очень нравится ответ. :)

Answer (score 2):

Помимо Толстого и Достоевского так говорили и другие известные люди.

В. О. Ключевский ("Курс русской истории"):
*Общий **факт тот, что** с половины XII столетия начался или, точнее, усилился отлив населения из центральной днепровской Руси к двум противоположным окраинам Русской земли...*

Н. К. Крупская ("Обучение и воспитание в школе"):
*Пусть начинания, инициатива того или иного учителя были наивны, разрозненны, не доводились до конца, оставались мало кому известны — **факт тот, что** они были, и это не могло не отразиться на всем школьном укладе, на всем духе школы.*

С. Ю. Витте ("Воспоминания"):
*...постоянно был среди военных у дяди моего генерала Фадеева и постоянно встречал выдающихся в России военных людей, — во всяком случае, **факт тот, что** я очень занимался пограничной стражей...*

Ничего не буду пересказывать, просто сошлюсь на Ушакова:
[**факт**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1074610), факта, муж. (лат. *factum*).
❖ **Факт, что** (разг.) — верно, несомненно, соответствует действительности, что…
«Но разве это не факт, что опубликование новой Конституции, Конституции социализма, было воспринято широкими массами и всеми нами, как дающее нечто новое, как открывающее новые перспективы в жизни народов СССР?» (Молотов).
**Факт тот, что** (разг.) — дело в том, что… (под влиянием выражения "дело в том, что" иногда ***неправильно говорят и "факт в том, что"***).

Сочетание с союзом (без пометок) [**факт (тот), что**](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=1675) представлено и в справочнике по пунктуации.
Для меня это обычное выражение (не часто, конечно, но я его использую).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!

Comment: @shampar Извините, в свое сообщение я никак не вкладывала такой смысл. Что значит "выражение допускали" — это Вы о Ключевском, Крупской и Витте? Так говорят — более сотни лет! — представители разных слоев: и писатели, и ученые, и политики. Я специально привела именно эти цитаты — времен Достоевского и Толстого. Есть еще и Андроников, и Богомолов (более "поздние").

Comment: «Я  никак не вкладывала...» Я-то вкладывал лишь один смысл: тексты пишут, не говорят. (Странно толковать об этом, когда комментарий пропал,  а само замечание ничтожно. Не желал испортить Вам вечер.)

Comment: Был ведь не комментарий, а правка (а ее всегда можно посмотреть)... Всё-всё, не фырчу больше (так... навалилась ерунда всякая,  ненужная). И Вам — доброй ночи!

Comment: @shampar: а зачем Вы приписку про курсив сделали в моём вопросе?